# Facebook Graph API: Attend event

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My question is: how can I use the graph api to let the logged in user attend an event?

In another question I saw a solution to this: doing a POST request to graph.facebook.com/{eventid}/attending, but Facebook's documentation doesn't say anything about how to let the user attend an event.

Is this even possible?

Comment: The necessary permission is still listed, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-rsvp_event - but I am not sure if you actually can still reply in the name of the user, so you’d have to test that.

Comment: Just tested it and POSTing to /eventid/attending with the 'rsvp_event' permission works.

Answer (score 1):

**As of April 24, 2018, this is not possible** since you can no longer perform `POST` operations on the `attending`, `maybe`, `interested`, and `declined` edges of the Graph API.

See: [Breaking Changes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/#events-api-4-24)